# Why is my Gravatar blank at GitHub's Pulse view?

Tags: github, gravatar

On every [Pulse page on GitHub](https://github.com/Rob--W/pdf.js/pulse), a default Gravatar is shown instead of my usual one:

[image]

I'm using two email accounts on GitHub, one for logging in, and another one for blaming. Both accounts are correctly set up to my GitHub page and at Gravatar.com; my Gravatar is clearly visible in all issues and commits, but not at the Pulse page (for the record, the hash of the image is `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`, an empty string).

How can I get my Gravatar to show up, instead of a blank one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filled a contact form at https://help.github.com/contact, and got the following reply within a few days:

> Hey Rob
>
> Sorry for the delay getting back to you. We pushed out a fix for this
> a few hours ago. You should be showing up correctly in Pulse pages
> now. Let me know if you're still having any trouble.
>
> Cheers
> Brian

Indeed, the issue has been resolved for me. As a bonus, my Gravatar also shows up before the box of commits that used to be blank for me as well. [Example](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/87#commits-pushed-05790dc):

#### Before

[image: screenshot with default Gravatar before box of commits]

#### After

[image: screenshot with my Gravatar before box of commits]